# RABL child block yields child object instead of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rabl

According to the [RABL documentation under "Child nodes"](https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails#child-nodes), the following is possible:

```
object @user
child :posts do |user|
  attribute :title unless user.suspended?
end
```

This implies that the `user` variable yielded by the block is the parent object `@user`.

However, when I attempt the following:

```
collection @listings
child :address do |listing|
  attribute :number_and_street unless listing.address_hidden?
end
```

I get a `NoMethodError`:

```
undefined method `address_hidden?' for #<Address:0x007fb83d6eaf80>
```

meaning that the block is yielding the child address object instead of the parent `@listing` object, as implied by the documentation.

The only way around this that I can see is something like `address.listing.address_hidden?`, which would result in way too many database queries, so I'd like to avoid that.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to fix this behavior?

Comment: look into Active Model Serializers - much simpler than rabl IMHO

Comment: Thanks @timpone, but I have to use RABL because it has capabilities I need that Active Model Serializers don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use collection the child block does not yield the individual objects.
What I would do is split it in two files.

index.json.rabl

```
collection @listing
extends "app/view/listings/base"
```

base.json.rabl

```
object @listing
child :address do |listing|
  attribute :number_and_street unless listing.address_hidden?
end
```

EDIT:
I just noticed you're using the rabl-rails gem. My solution works for 'rabl', I am not too sure about this gem :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining that difference, everything makes sense now!